# How to change the eventBorderColor thickness in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I'm currently using the Calendar Plugin (fullcalendar). I just couldn't find in its CSS file where I can customize the width/thickness of the eventBorderColor. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the class .fc-event-inner:

```
.fc-event-inner {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Or you can use the 'className' option on your event objects and create that class. Be sure you add the !important property.

```
{
   title  : 'event01',
   start  : '2014-08-09',
   className: 'moreBorder'
}


.moreBorder{
  border: 5px solid red !important;
}
```