# How to change the Full Calendar plugin events's border colour?

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

I have this [full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) (v3.4.0) plugin. I have downloaded the CSS for it from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css). I have almost fully customised it. However, I have spent an hour trying to figure out how to change the `border-color` for all the events. I have found out this `eventBorderColor` form [full calendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventBorderColor) but I am not sure how I can use it.

I have tried the following but none of them worked:

```
fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end {
    border-color: red;
}
```

and this:

```
.fc-event {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

I have tried this one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130026/how-to-change-the-eventbordercolor-thickness-in-fullcalendar):

```
.fc-event-inner {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Screen shot of the events:

[image]

Screen shot of the Developer's Tool: There are some styles that are given using inline styles and they don't exist in the file. These inline styles seem to have higher priority when I try to take out the `border-color` the actual border is applied.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
border: 5px solid red !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by using `borderColor: 'red'` in JavaScript for each event when I am displaying it on the calendar.